# Selective Drag and Drop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I have two JLists and two JTextfields, i want to be able to to drag from one JList to one of the JTextfields, and then the other JList would drag to the other JTextField, however i do not want the first JList being able to drag and drop in the second text field and vice verca.  So how would i go about doing this, i have scoured the Oracle java tutorial but didnt find anything useful?

Here is the TransferHandler class i am using on the JTextfields:

```
class CustomTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
int action;

public CustomTransferHandler(int action) {
    this.action = action;
    }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY;
    }

    public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        return new StringSelection(((JTextComponent) c).getSelectedText());
    }

    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        // for the demo, we'll only support drops (not clipboard paste)
        if (!support.isDrop()) {
            return false;
        }

        // we only import Strings
        if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean actionSupported = (action & support.getSourceDropActions()) == action;
        if (actionSupported) {
            support.setDropAction(action);
            return true;
        }


        return false;
    }

    public boolean importData(TransferSupport ts) {
        try {
            ((JTextComponent) ts.getComponent())
                .setText((String) ts
                         .getTransferable()
                         .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
            return true;
        } catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```